# Change date format in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

```
my date = "29-07-2015"
```

what I want: `"2015-07-29"`

This works in irb but not my ruby file:

```
date.gsub(/(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})/, '\3-\2-\1')
```

Is there an alternative way to do this?

Comment: If it works in irb it should work in a file. Maybe try printing the value of `date` before using `gsub` to make sure that it is what you think it is?

Comment: Yeah I've tried that using logger.info.

Answer (score 6):

Just parse and rewrite:

```
require 'date'

d = Date.strptime('29-07-2015', '%d-%m-%Y')

d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
# => "2015-07-29"
```

The `strptime` function and `strftime` function take the same formatting options, so they can undo what the other produces.

Answer (score 0):

With regex, something like that:

```
(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})
```

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/bP3rY0/1)

Answer (score 0):

Without regex, but will solve your problem:

`"29-07-2015".split('-').reverse.join('-')`

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is `my_date.reverse!`. All you want is to flip that date, and it is a string. Strings can be reversed.